# Path analysis - model writing check (Rstudio- lavaan package)

Tags: r, lavaan

Below you will find the Figure of the path model that I wrote in Rstudio.

[image]

> model2 <- '

- #direct effect
- INT ~ e*PN
- PN ~ d*AR
- AR ~ c*AC
- AC ~ b*PB
- PB ~ a*BV
- #indirect effect
- ed := e * d
- edc := e * d * c
- edcb := e * d * c * b
- edcba := e * d * c * b * a
- totalind:= ed + edc + edcb + edcba
- total:= e + ed + edc + edcb + edcba
- '

> fit_model <-lavaan::sem(model2, data = Data, estimator='MLR')
> summary(fit_model, fit.measures=TRUE, ci=TRUE

I am wondering if you agree with how I wrote the model, particularly, the totalind that corresponds to the sum of all indirect effects and the total.

Thanks in advance,
María

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wondering if you agree with how I wrote the model, particularly, the `totalind` that corresponds to the sum of all indirect effects and the `total`.

No, total (indirect) effects would be the sum of all (in)direct effects from one predictor (e.g., `BV`) to one outcome (e.g., `INT`).  In your model, there is only 1 path from `BV` to `INT`, and it is the indirect effect you labeled `edcba`.  There is no other path, so there is no "total" to calculate.  If you included a direct effect in your model syntax (`INT ~ dir*BV`), then the total effect would be `total := dir + edcba`).  Likewise, if you included other effects of `BV` on other mediators, you could have other indirect paths.  For example, `PN ~ f*BV` would create another indirect effect (`ef := e*f`), so you could calculate a total indirect effect (`totalind := edcba + ef`) and total effect (`total := dir + edcba + ef`).  It gets more complicated as you add more effects, but that is the basic idea.

Comment: Hi Terrence, thank you very much for your kind answer!

Comment: Hi Maria, please remember to vote, indicating whether this answer helps.